# Porque mi server node me devuelve este error Error: request entity too large?

Tags: nodejs

Intento hacer un login with github pero en el backend de Node cuando hago el intercambio del code que me devuelve git por callback por un acces_token tengo este error

```
Error: request entity too large
```

```js
fetch('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token/', {
    method: 'POST',
    client_id: 'xxxx',
    client_secret: 'xxxx',
    code: req.params.code,
    accept: 'json',
}).then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
}).then(function(body) {
    res.json(body);
});
```

Esto devuelve si se hace por POSTMAN por ej algo como esto

```
access_token=e5248cf7809a8f3da6f4c730bf80af12ef32c3cc&scope=user&token_type=bearer
```

Comment: Debes aumentar el tamaño de la peticion de tu servidor, eso sucede porque son peticiones bastante pesadas, y debe estár en la configuración de tu servidor, lo que hace es que al ser tan pesado lo aborta con un código http 413, estas usando algún servidor proxy?

Comment: Ahora edite la pregunta y puse lo que deberia responder esto, no parece muy pesado, tu que dices?

Comment: deberias mejorar tu pregunta "Porque esto me devuelve esto?" no da una idea de nada.

Comment: Buen punto, ya la modifique. Gracias Rene

Comment: La experiencia que he tenido con ese error (Http 413) es cuando he intentado hacer una peticion con un archivo grande al servidor, este lo aborta, usualmente eso no se da en servidores para entornos de desarrollo si no en producción, aquella vez usaba un proxy con nginx y en la configuracion de nginx cambie el tamaño de la peticion a unos 20M